# Converting a palette to another color

Tags: css, colors, hex

I'm trying to convert the page of a whole website from pink to green. They've used a pink palette that works very well together and i need to convert the palette to a green version, but just cant seem to get it to work along.

**Current Palette**

```
#fff0f0

#b18585

#b18597

#ffe3e2

#ffe9e9

#f9c4d2
```

Any suggestions on how i could get these colors converted into a green palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all the colors from HEX to HSL, then adjust the hue (the first number) by 120 degrees for each color.

Then convert back to hex if you want but there's really no need, CSS support HSLA.

Example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.pink.a {
  background: hsla(0, 25%, 50%, 1)
}

.green.a {
  background: hsla(120, 25%, 50%, 1)
}

.pink.b {
  background: hsla(0, 22%, 61%, 1)
}

.green.b {
  background: hsla(120, 22%, 61%, 1)
}

.pink.c {
  background: hsla(335, 22%, 61%, 1)
}

.green.c {
  background: hsla(95, 22%, 61%, 1) /* 355 + 120 - 360 = 95*/
}
```

```html
<div class="pink a"></div>
<div class="pink b"></div>
<div class="pink c"></div>

<div class="green a"></div>
<div class="green b"></div>
<div class="green c"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this: `#f0f19c, #bec020, #acad4c, #dddf90, #eaebb2, #d7d95a`:
[image]